# Unity IOC - How to register Types based on Custom Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a large ASP.Net web app which uses Unity IOC throughout.  There are a number of classes that need to be created as singletons.

This is the first part of the code in my UnityConfig.cs in my startup project:

```
// Create new Unity Container
var container = new UnityContainer();

// Register All Types by Convention by default
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.Transient);
```

Up to now, I have specifically registered each of the singleton types in the Unity IOC container, with a lifetime manager, as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<IMySingleton1, MySingleton1>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IMySingleton2, MySingleton2>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

However, I would like to move away from specifically registering each type as a singleton in this way, identify which types within the loaded assemblies are required to be singletons by tagging them with a custom SingletonAttribute, and then, if possible, register them en masse.

I've created a custom attribute for the purpose:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SingletonAttribute : Attribute {}
```

And tagged the class definitions accordingly:

```
[Singleton]
public class MySingleton : IMySingleton
{
 ...
}
```

I've managed to select all the types that have this custom attribute:

```
static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithSingletonAttribute(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SingletonAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following code in the UnityConfig.cs:

```
// Identify Singleton Types
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

List<Type> singletonTypes = new List<Type>();
foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    singletonTypes.AddRange(GetTypesWithSingletonAttribute(assembly));
}
```

So, I now have an enumeration with all the required types, but I can't see how to register them as singletons by type while still enabling them to be resolved by convention (i.e. so Unity knows that IMySingleton should be resolved to an instance of MySingleton).

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to constrain the types returned to types that are annotated with the `Singleton` attribute:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
        .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<SingletonAttribute>(true).Any()),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

You could register everything and then overwrite the registration for any singletons with a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`:

```
// Register All Types by Convention by default
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.Transient);

// Overwrite All Types marked as Singleton
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
        .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<SingletonAttribute>(true).Any()),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
    null,
    true); // Overwrite existing mappings without throwing
```

Comment: Genius! Just what I was looking for.  Thank you so much. :)